# how can I solve this problem with sum function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am studying javascipt and meet a very small exercise like this.

Create a sum function with 2 parameters a and b. This is a function which mean they will make the summation between two numbers. The function will return the result of a + b.

Here is my code

```
function sum(a,b) {
c=a+b;
console.log(c);
}
writelog(sum);
```

But it said to me that there are some errors in my code, so could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What is `writelog`?

Comment: You need to call the function with arguments in parentheses: `console.log(sum(3, 5))`

Comment: The function needs to **return** the sum, not print it.

Comment: Please clearly state what is the error you are getting and what do you actually want to achieve  over here. If you are just practising questions, don't cheat by asking here :D

Comment: See [Difference between console.log and return in javascript?](/q/21020608/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Your instructions say that the function should *return* the result, not print it. The printing should be done by the caller.

You need to supply arguments when calling the function.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}
console.log(sum(5, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code using wrong function `console.log` instead of `writelog`.

Second, your function should `return` value instead of console log inside it.

Third, when you call function need input `parameter` for it.

```js
function sum(a,b) {
let c=a+b;
return c;
}
console.log(sum(5,6));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}
const answer = sum(5,6)
console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score -2):

WHy use writelog?. I suggest you to use `console.log()`. This is the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) reference:

```
function sum(a , b) {
  const c = a + b;
  return c;
}

console.log(sum(5,6));
```

Comment: I don't know. lol